# await Task.WhenAll como executar vários processos?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async

Estou tentando criar diversas task (async) elas irão executar a seguinte lógica:

1. Fazer o Parse de um Html com base em uma url recebida com o HtmlAgilityPack
2. Retornar uma model produto após o parse
3. Inserir o Produto no database
4. Fazer download das imagens do produto
5. Marcar url como lida

os itens 1 e 4, principalmente o 4 demoram por causa da velocidade do link da internet, então por isso eles devem ser async.
Porém estou com dificuldades, todo meu código roda, porém de forma sincrona.

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
{
     IEnumerable<UrlsProdutos> registros = db.UrlsTable.Where(w => w.Lido == false).Take(1000);

  ExecutaTarefasAsync(registros).Wait();
}


  public static async Task ExecutaTarefasAsync(IEnumerable<UrlsProdutos> registros)
        {
            var urlTasks = registros.Select((registro, index) =>
            {
                Task downloadTask = default(Task);

                //parsing html
                var produtoTask =  ExtraiDados.ParseHtml(registro.Url);
                if (produtoTask.IsCompleted)
                {
                    var produto = produtoTask.Result;
                    //aqui faço um insert com Dapper
                    downloadTask = InsertAdo.InsertAdoStpAsync(produto);
                }

                //marca url como lida, igual ao insert do produto
                InsertAdo.MarcaComoLido(registro.UrlProdutoId);

                Output(index);

                return downloadTask;
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);
        }

        public static void Output(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Executando {id.ToString()}");
        }
```

O insert fiz um fixo só para testar

```
public static async Task InsertAdoStpAsync(Imovel imovel)
{
    var stringConnection = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
    var con = new SqlConnection(stringConnection);
    var sqlQuery = "insert tblProdutos...etc..etc"
    con.ExecuteAsync(sqlQuery);
}
```

Não sei se cada função deve ser async. ou se eu poderia selecionar tipo o Download e o parse ser async..

O meu sistema de download de fotos async funciona perfeitamente.

```
  public static async Task DownloadData(IEnumerable<FotosProdutos> urls)
        {
            var urlTasks = urls.Select((url, index) =>
            {
                var filename = "";

                var wc = new WebClient();
                string path = "C:\teste\" + url.FileName;

                var downloadTask = wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), path);
                return downloadTask;
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);
        }
```

**Preciso de ajuda para fazer e entender como o ExecutaTarefasAsync ser realmente async igual ao fotos que hj nem consegui ainda incorporar nesse projeto.**

OBS: Não sei se o download das fotos faço lá no parse ou se coloco nessa task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um ponto que eu sempre reforço em questões sobre async/await: ele não torna a execução de um método assíncrona por si só, apenas permite ao programador escrever métodos em um fluxo de execução próximo ao que seria escrito para métodos síncronos. A grande questão, é que async/await sinaliza ao compilador que ao encontrar um await, irá esperar até que a execução seja finalizada, mas sem bloquear a Thread principal (Thead de UI em Windows Forms ou Thread do pipeline do IIS em aplicações web, por exemplo).

Sobre o seu caso em específico, o uso de async/await não está correto. Quando um método é async, apesar de você dizer que ele retorna um Task, não significa que quem usa ele necessita pegar essa Task como um retorno. Ao utilizar o await em sua chamada, você já está dizendo ao compilador que ele deve esperar a execução do método. Não sei se consegui explicar de maneira clara, mas acho que com o exemplo vai dar pra entender essa dinâmica.

Para tornar a execução realmente assíncrona, em questão de fazer com que cada registro execute em Threads diferentes de forma "paralela", eu fiz o seguinte:

```
// fiz as classes aqui só pra conseguir executar e mostrar um caso de execução com 5 segundos de duração pra cada chamada

public class FotosProdutos
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class UrlsProdutos
{
    public int UrlProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Imovel
{

}

public class InsertAdo
{
    public static async Task InsertAdoStpAsync(Imovel imovel, int index)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - InsertAdoStpAsync {1}", DateTime.Now, index));
    }

    public static async Task MarcaComoLido(int urlProdutoId, int index)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - MarcaComoLido {1}", DateTime.Now, index));
    }
}

public class ExtraiDados
{
    public static async Task<Imovel> ParseHtml(string url, int index)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - ParseHtml {1}", DateTime.Now, index));

        return new Imovel();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // coloquei qualquer coisa aqui só pra eu conseguir reproduzir sem a sua dependência de Dapper
        IEnumerable<UrlsProdutos> registros = new List<UrlsProdutos>() { new UrlsProdutos { UrlProdutoId = 1 }, new UrlsProdutos { UrlProdutoId = 2 }, new UrlsProdutos { UrlProdutoId = 3 } };

        // Roda uma Task diferente pra cada registro.
        // Do jeito que você estava fazendo, sem o Task.Run(), acontecia basicamente a mesma coisa que um loop for executando item a item sincronamente a sua coleção
        var tarefas = registros.Select((registro, index) =>
        {
            return Task.Run(async () => await ExecutaTarefaAsync(registro, index));
        });

        Task.WaitAll(tarefas.ToArray());

        // espera mais um pouco só pra vermos uma diferença até o log de fim
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - Acabou!", DateTime.Now));

        Console.Read();
    }

    // Mudei o seu método pra se referir apenas a um registro só pra ser mais didático
    public static async Task ExecutaTarefaAsync(UrlsProdutos registro, int index)
    {
        Output(index);

        // chama o seu método de parse, falando pra esperar tudo o que tiver de assíncrono nele, e pega o retorno logo em seguida
        var produto = await ExtraiDados.ParseHtml(registro.Url, index);

        // como o seu parse já acabou, insere o registro com o resultado dele
        await InsertAdo.InsertAdoStpAsync(produto, index);

        // por fim, marcar todo mundo como lido
        await InsertAdo.MarcaComoLido(registro.UrlProdutoId, index);

        Output(index);
    }

    // não usei, mas mudei ele pra você ver a questão do await
    public static async Task DownloadData(FotosProdutos url, int index)
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();
        string path = @"C:\teste\" + url.FileName;

        // aqui você não precisa pegar a Task, ao usar o await ele já entende que você quer esperar o resultado do método async pra prosseguir na execução do método
        await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url.Url), path);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - DownloadData {1}", DateTime.Now, index.ToString()));
    }

    public static void Output(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - Executando {1}", DateTime.Now, id.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Ao executar esse exemplo, tive a seguinte saída:

```
13/10/2016 00:56:27 - Executando 1
13/10/2016 00:56:27 - Executando 2
13/10/2016 00:56:27 - Executando 0
13/10/2016 00:56:32 - ParseHtml 1
13/10/2016 00:56:32 - ParseHtml 2
13/10/2016 00:56:32 - ParseHtml 0
13/10/2016 00:56:37 - InsertAdoStpAsync 0
13/10/2016 00:56:37 - InsertAdoStpAsync 1
13/10/2016 00:56:37 - InsertAdoStpAsync 2
13/10/2016 00:56:42 - MarcaComoLido 2
13/10/2016 00:56:42 - MarcaComoLido 1
13/10/2016 00:56:42 - Executando 2
13/10/2016 00:56:42 - Executando 1
13/10/2016 00:56:42 - MarcaComoLido 0
13/10/2016 00:56:42 - Executando 0
13/10/2016 00:56:42 - Acabou!
```

Ou seja: como cada método leva 5 segundos pra executar, podemos observar que ele criou uma Thread diferente pra cada registro.

Comment: vou reproduzir seu código aqui, mas de ante-mão obrigado pela aula!, muito bom, bem detalhado...

Comment: só uma dúvida o DownloadData, qual seria o local correto? no parse produtos? ou lá na raiz no program.cs no executar tarefas? pq ele é o que mais demora e ele só pode ser executado depois que o parseHtml é concluido e retorna o model produto.

Comment: @Dorathoto como você falou que faz parte dos seus passos fazer o download baseado no seu parse, eu colocaria uma chamada dentro do ExecutaTarefaAsync().

Como o processamento de cada imagem parece ser independente, eu testaria a diferença entre executar a lista em paralelo ou um a um pra ver em qual a aplicação renderia melhor.

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer uma funcao assincrona, voce utiliza a `Task`, como voce ja descobriu. O jeito certo de fazer algo desse tipo é assim:

```
public static Task MakeRequest(int i) { 

    return Task.Run(() => {

       // seu codigo aqui
    });

}

public static void Main(string[]) {

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(MakeRequestAsync(i));
    }

    // Aguarda todos MakeRequestAsync terminarem.
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Dessa maneira, quando voce chamar `MakeRequestAsync` voce pode usar o `await` como é esperado com métodos assíncronos:

```
var resp = await MakeRequestAsync(i);
```

Vale a pena dizer também que uma `Task` não dá garantias nenhuma de quando vai ser executada: pode tanto começar a ser executada imediatamente quanto ficar na fila.

Outra coisa importante é entender a diferença de `Task.WhenAll` e `Task.WaitAll`.
`Task.WhenAll` retorna uma outra `Task` que você pode esperar (`await`) no momento em que for interessante, e o código continua rodando, ou seja, é uma função "não bloqueante". Já a `Task.WaitAll` vai parar o fluxo do código até que todas `Task`s sejam executadas.

Resumindo: seu método que deve ser assíncrono deve, na verdade, disparar uma `Task` e retornar um objeto `awaitable`. A maneira mais fácil de se fazer isso é utilizando `Task.Run`.