# WebClientDownloadFileTaskAsync arquivo em uso, mesmo com Dispose

Tags: c#, asynctask, webclient

Estou fazendo download de 10 imagens ao mesmo tempo de forma async, Porém na 2ª foto normalmente da erro de que a imagem está em uso.

> The process can not access the file because it is being used by
>   another process.

Já acho estranho, pois o código antigo que movia as imagens após o download já foi removido, ou seja, não estou fazendo nda além do download, então não deveria dar esse erro.

Meu código está assim:

```
    public static async Task DownloadImgAsync(IEnumerable<FotosProduto> urls, int id)
    {
//recebe uma lista com 10 urls para download
            var urlTasks = urls.Select((url, index) =>
            {
                using (var wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    var urlTratada = url.Url.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\n", "");
//garantindo que a url está correta
                    var path = Caminhos.FolderImg + url.FileNameFinal;
//aqui só recupero a pasta default das minhas imagens + o nome final da foto
                    var downloadTask = wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urlTratada), path);
//insere o processo na task de download
                    wc.Dispose(); //redudante pelo using, mas ainda sim pra tentar evitar o erro.
                    return downloadTask;
                }
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);
    }
```

Veja que já coloquei ele com `using` e pra desencargo de consciência ainda chamo `dispose`, porém ele sempre retorna que a imagem está em uso. como?

OBS: Essa função é chamada para cada produto, normalmente tenho uma lista grande de produtos rodando ex: 1000mil produtos e cada produto 10 imagens.

**Outras perguntas minhas referente ao mesmo projeto:**

[Download Async + Copy = Copiando imagem 0 bytes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158823/download-async-copy-copiando-imagem-0-bytes)

[await Task.WhenAll como executar vários processos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158098/await-task-whenall-como-executar-v%C3%A1rios-processos/158452#158452)

Comment: Já verificou se ele está tentando baixar ao mesmo tempo a mesma imagem? Se for o caso esse `path` seu pode ter o mesmo valor em duas tasks ao mesmo tempo, aí ele daria esse erro.

Comment: perfeita a resposta, pode ser que meu gerador aleatório não esteja tão aleatório assim, isso justificaria a falha...vou testar

Comment: A nível de teste (ou de produção, vai saber) faz o nome usando um `DateTime.Now.Ticks` + `Random`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o problema era por algum motivo a minha função de gerar nome aleatório não era tão aleatório assim:

```
  public string GerarNomeJPG(int _size)
        {
            var random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            char ch;
            for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
            {
                ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
                builder.Append(ch);
            }
            builder.Append(".jpg");
            return builder.ToString().ToLower();
        }
```

Solução graças ao comentário do [@Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24542/ricardo)